# Unable to see activities older than 2 years

Tags: reporting, nonprofit-starter-pack

I'm working with a non-profit organization and I'm trying to run a report on all the activities, but only the last 2 years are showing up in the report. Is that a limitation in Salesforce org for non-profit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Salesforce archives activities more than 365 days old](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005175&type=1). You can [increase the archive days for your organization](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000175889&type=1) to show more than 365 days worth. Note that these activities can still be seen on records, and exported via Export All (e.g. Data Loader). This is not a NPO-specific limitation, but rather a feature designed to keep reports from slowing down as organizations build up years of activity history.

Comment: How do you access these archived activities

Comment: @HUBBY0716 You can export them via [Data Export](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_exportdata.htm&type=5), or by using the [Apex Data Loader](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_loader.htm&type=5) "Export All" mode, or other tools that can generate a "queryAll" API call.

Comment: yeah. I figured it out, but thank you!